# Stolarsky representation from Zeckendorf representation with some pairs of bits inverted

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, sequences-and-series, integer-sequences, fibonacci-numbers

- Let $a(n)$ be [A200714](https://oeis.org/A200714) i.e. Stolarsky representation interpreted as binary to decimal integers.
- Let $b(n)$ be [A003714](https://oeis.org/A003714) i.e. Fibbinary numbers (Zeckendorf representation interpreted as binary to decimal integers).
- Let $f(n)$ be [A000045](https://oeis.org/A000045) i.e. Fibonacci numbers. Here
  $$
  f(n)=f(n-1)+f(n-2), \\
  f(0)=0, f(1) = 1
  $$
- Let $g(n)$ be [A130312](https://oeis.org/A130312) i.e. each Fibonacci number $f(n)$ appears $f(n)$ times.
- Let $c(n)$ be is the same as $a(f(g(n)+3)-n)$ with rewrite $1 \to 0$, $0 \to 10$ applied to binary expansion (with $1$ prepended and rightmost $0$ extracted).

I conjecture that we can get $c(n)$ from $b(n)$ inverting some pairs of bits. Here is the algorithm:

- Start with the second bit (from the left side) in the Zeckendorf representation of n.
- Search for a pair $10$.
- If there is no such pair, do nothing.
- If you find such pair, keep moving while the every next pair of bits equals $10$.
- If you have reached the end of the representation in this way and it ends with $10$ (or $100$), invert every pair of bits equals $10$ lying after the starting pair equals $10$. After that, do nothing.
- If you have reached the end of the representation in this way and it ends with $101$, do nothing.
- If you end with $1000$, invert every pair of bits equals $10$ lying between the starting pair equals $10$ and pair of zeros (in the end of $1000$), then choose the next bit after $1000$ and go back to step 2.
- If you end with $1001$, invert last pair of bits in this quadruple, then choose the next bit after this quadruple and go back to step 2.

Here by doing nothing I mean stopping and exiting the loop.

Here is the PARI/GP program to check it numerically:

```
stol(n) = {my(phi=quadgen(5)); if(n==1, [], if(n != round(round(n/phi)*phi), concat(stol(floor(n/phi^2) + 1), [0]), concat(stol(round(n/phi)), [1]))); }
a(n) = fromdigits(stol(n), 2);
g(n)=local(m); if(n<1, 0, m=0; until(fibonacci(m)>n, m++); m-2) \\ from A072649
Zeckendorf(n) = my(A = n, B1, B2, C, m = 1, v1); v1 = [1]; while(fibonacci(m+1) <= n, m++); m--; B1 = fibonacci(m+1); B2 = fibonacci(m); A -= B1; while(m > 1, m--; C = 0; if(A >= B2, A -= B2; C = 1); [B1, B2] = [B2, B1 - B2]; v1 = concat(v1, C)); v1
b1(n) = my(v1); v1 = Zeckendorf(n); my(A = 2); while(A <= #v1, while((A + 1) <= #v1 && !(v1[A] && !v1[A + 1]), A++); my(B = A); while((A + 2) <= #v1 && v1[A + 2], A += 2); if(A < #v1, if((A + 3) <= #v1 && v1[A + 3], B = A; A += 2); for(i = B + 2, A + 1, v1[i] = !v1[i])); A += 2); v1
b2(n) = if(n == 1, 0, n--; my(v1, v2); v1 = concat(b1(fibonacci(g(n) + 3) - n - 1), 0); v2 = [1]; if(#v1 > 2, my(A = 3); while(A <= #v1, if(v1[A], v2 = concat(v2, 0); A++, v2 = concat(v2, 1)); A++)); fromdigits(v2, 2))
test(n) = a(n) == b2(n)
```

Is there a way to prove it?